# Angular 4 + angular material 2 + angular flex-layout?

Tags: javascript, angular, grid, containers, angular-flex-layout

I'm kinda new in visual design. I'm using now angular 4 with material 2 module and with bootstrap for grid system. After all I realized that's not good enough (I started to don't like that's container sizes for 21:9 aspect ratio for example)
After all I found angular flex-layout module is the recommended for this setup. But I don't find a container like element in there, what should center the main content in the view and give a responsive element width to it.
What is the preferred method to set up a container with this setup whats like the bootstraps `'container'` class?

Answer (score 0):

For centering, I was using `fxLayoutAlign="center center"`. Here's an code sample from my app: https://github.com/Farata/angulartypescript/blob/master/chapter5/ng-auction/src/app/app.component.html

Here's the docs: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Implementation